# Insert url in one view and then display it in uiwebview in new view

Tags: iphone

hay all,
   I want to enter url in one view and then want to switch and display it in another view in uiwebView I am trying like this but its not working.

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
```

//Create a URL object.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
```

//URL Requst Object

```
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

//Load the request in the UIWebView.

```
[webViewController.page loadHTMLString:urlAddress baseURL:url];




webViewController *sec=[[webViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"webView" bundle:nil];
```

[self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];

can anybody help me, I am new to iphone World

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out,.....

I havent checked it but it will work

```
  NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

//Create a URL object.

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.   

webViewController *sec=[[webViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"webView" bundle:nil];
sec.webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
sec.webview.delegate=sec;
[sec.webview loadHTMLString:urlAddress baseURL:url];

[self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
```